# Best way to call JS files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I noticed my chartkick charts were not appearing and stuck on "loading..." within production.

I debugged and realized the reason is because i recently created a bunch of `.js` files under javascripts to cut down on `<script></script>` code within my views and instead using `<%= javascript_include_tag "word" %>`.

**What the problem is**, and the difference btween the charts showing and not showing is in my initializers/assets.rb folder is:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
```

Without this, it works, but also without it, i cannot load my independent JS files.

**How can I load my JS files**, under assets/javascripts/file_name.js and also have my charts working?

Is there a better way to call my JS files, without needing to use script tags?

Application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

//= require jquery3 #i have this here and not over popper because if it isn't in this position, most of my javascript/jquery features under bootstrap do not work - i haven't figured this out yet.  I will most likely use pure jquery/JS and remove all bootstrap JS if I cannot find this reason

//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: js is not compiled

Comment: Did you add those files to the tree in app/assets/javascripts/application.js?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Comment: Can you give an example on doing that to elaborate? And to clarify, I have no issues with this files working, its only when i don't use the precompile line of code in the assets folder, the chart works.. with it, the charts will not work.  If i dont use it i would need to use script tags which i do not want to do just to have the charts working.  There needs to be some sort of workaround for this.  and this all aowkrs locally, just not in production

Comment: @WilliamRWilson I am under the impression that any files under assets/javascripts/file_name.js should automatically load and are included in the tree? I have edited my OP to include my application.js

Comment: require_tree should load all the files in the app/assets/javascripts folder, but it does so in a particular order which has created trouble for me in the past.  I have taken to listing out every file explicitly in the application.js, (eg //= require file_name) although that may be cargo culting in my case.

Comment: If i dont use `<%= javascript_include_tag 'file_name %>` the JS won't go to action.  When using that, my app won't work unless i precompile the files in initializers/assets.  If i precompile them, the charts won't work.  I'm beginning to assume this is a bug with the chartkick

Comment: And my only other options, unless there's a fix for this.... is to use `<script>` code which i want to avoid.